# WCF: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, 64-bit

I created a simple WCF application. The platform is set to Any CPU. I can build and run the application successfully. But when I change the platform to x64 I get the following error:

> *Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata*

My system has 64 bit OS. Actually i have to set the platform to x64 to laod a dll in my app. What would be the possible reasons for this error. Please help me.

I am using IIS Express.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: check out similar blog

[Reference blog][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199541/failed-to-add-a-service-service-metadata-may-not-be-accessible-make-sure-your

Comment: Try changing the application pool Managed Pipeline Mode to Classic

Comment: @Sajeetharan From where can i change this?

Comment: Do you use IIS or is it a windows service? Where does this error occur exactly? Debuging, startup, etc...

Comment: iis. error occurs at startup.

Comment: In case you are using IIS Express and VS2013, you would need to check the following option in VS Options: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects

Comment: I posted that as an answer and added the comment in your question about usage of IIS Express, since that information was crucial for solving your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using IIS Express and VS2013, you  need to check the following option in VS Options when debugging x64 web project:

`Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects`

Answer (score 3):

IIS -> Advanced Settings of Application Pool. Set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to true. Also check if the Service is depending on a library that is not x64.